# Shopping Cart with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a shopping cart with Vanilla JavaScript and i'm trying with Console.Log to show price of product "$19.99" when i click button to remove the product, but it's not showing nothing in Console.Log and i think problem is with html but i cannot find it, any idea?

```
<div class="click-cart">
    <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span></div>
      <div class="olp">
        <div class="lakn">
        <img class="shop-item-cart" src="https://cdn.thewirecutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/canon-dslrs-march-2018-2x1-lowres3496.jpg">
        <span class="shop-title">Album 1</span>
        <span class="shop-price">$19.99</span>
        <input class="quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
        <button class="delete-cart">X</button>
      </div></div>
        <div class="clear-checkout">
      <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>
      <button class="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button></div>
    <div class="cart-items">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-total">
          <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
          <span class="cart-total-price">$10.79</span>
      </div>
```

````
    for (let i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    let button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let buttonCliked = event.target
    buttonCliked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal ()
    })
}

function updateCartTotal () {
    let cartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.click-cart');
    let cartRows = cartItemContainer.querySelector('.cart-row');
    for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        let cartRow = cartRows[i]
        let priceElement = cartRow.querySelector('.shop-price');
        let quantityElement = cartRow.querySelector('.quantity-input');
        let price = priceElement.innerText
        console.log(price)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cart-row">
    <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
    <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
    <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
</div>
```

The `shop-price` element is not in the `cart-row` div.

Furthermore, your for loop would not run because `cartRows` is not an array, instead it is a single `HTMLElement` with a length of `undefined`, use `cartItemContainer.querySelectorAll('.cart-row')` to get an interable `NodeList` instead.

Additionally, since you delete the element before you use the updateCartTotal function it is necessary to have a price variable preset to 0.

```
function updateCartTotal () {
let cartItemContainer = document.querySelector('.click-cart');
let cartRows = cartItemContainer.querySelectorAll('.cart-row');
let price = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    let cartRow = cartRows[i]
    let priceElement = cartRow.querySelector('.shop-price');
    let quantityElement = cartRow.querySelector('.quantity-input');
    if (priceElement) {
      price += Number(priceElement.innerText.replace('$',''));
    }
    console.log(price);
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but it's showing this error "Cannot read property 'innerText' of null", Check my Codepen and change querySelector to querySelectorAll and you can see error in Console.Log
https://codepen.io/beh4r/pen/dravvJ

Comment: Ah I see you delete the shop-price element anyways. Give me a second

Comment: yeah i see now, but if i try and replace           "<div class="olp">
            <div class="lakn"">, these div classes which price it is and change them with "<div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-row">" still not working?

Comment: It's because you run the function updateCartTotal after you delete the element, thus you can't get it, because it no longer exists

Comment: I'm following a YouTube tutorial and it's literally the same method he's applying i'm doing the same 
https://prnt.sc/n21oyo

Comment: and you code works now thanks mate, but i still don't get why this code of mine doesn't show in Console Log the price as this YouTube video does from min 12:10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeFzkC2awTM&t=652s

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns an interable NodeList, unlike, `.querySelector()` which you used instead? Because it's not iterable the for loop never runs

Comment: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Introduction-to-Web-Development/blob/master/Introduction%20to%20JavaScript/Lesson%201/store.js#L89

Oh hey look what I found, this guy ends up doing something similar to what I did.

Comment: Yeah your code looks almost same as him and i was trying to Console Log every step to make sure to know if everything is going ok so i will try with your line of code you added to Codepen , thank you

Comment: Also note that I moved the closing div of cart-row to the end of the file. Make sure to accept this as the answer if it works.